# jQuery ().scrollTop() wont work with 'body' selector

Tags: jquery, events, null, selector, scrolltop

I have a problem with the jQuery ().scrollTop() function, which wont work with anything than (window) as selector. My setup is as follows:

```
 p = $('body').scrollTop();
    console.log(p);
    $('body').scroll(function(){
    if($('body').scrollTop()==0){
    $('.shadow').fadeOut();
    console.log('fadeout');}
    else{
    $('.shadow').fadeIn();
    console.log('fadein');}     
    });
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/HiAIh/

A basic page with header and an Overlay, problem is the shadow I want under my header if `('body').scrollTop()` is more than 0 which is not working. I also tried to assign a class to body or to wrap the whole thing in an additional DiV. The return value for the console.log is allways "null" instead of "0".
I also can not change the function to `(window).scrollTop()` which would work fine, because then my overlay is not working anymore. The window selector refers to the "html"-tag which I had to set overflow:hidden; for the overlay to work. 
That version you can see here:

```
 p = $(window).scrollTop();
   console.log(p);
   $(window).scroll(function(){
   if($(window).scrollTop()==0){
   $('.shadow').fadeOut();
   console.log('fadeout');}
   else{
   $('.shadow').fadeIn();
   console.log('fadein');}      
   });
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/CqGKg/

The shadow works just fine, but as you see the overlay wont.. Thats why i need to try to get the shadow to work in my first example `(('body').scrollTop())` with "html" overflow:hidden;

I googled a lot and tried many suggestions but without success..

Thanks a lot for your help!!

Comment: Please post some of your code and markup here so that the question and answers will be preserved for future generations of SO'ers. Welcome to SO!

Comment: @Jay Blanchard Thanks!

Comment: Wrap your jQuery in a document ready handler - when I did that it worked fine in FF.

Comment: It does something in the console, so the return value is not "null" anymore. But the shadow still wont show, the console returns event.returnValue is deprecated. Please use the standard event.preventDefault() instead.

Comment: but you are right Jay, in FF it is working allthough there is the error even in IE it works.. but not in Chrome. Thanks anyway you helped me a lot!